# Macro ending early - not running up till last cell in the column

Tags: excel, vba

Currently, I have the following set of codes which is to help me run `Macro1` for every cell in Column D, so long each cell is not blank/empty. However, with the codes below, it is not calling `Macro1` at the last **not empty/blank** cell of the column. Any idea why is it so?

An update: I found that the loop ended early at `Next R`. It didn't proceed on. Any idea why so?

```
Sub testing()

    Dim Rl As Long                      ' last row
    Dim Tmp As Variant
    Dim CellValue As Range
    Dim R As Long                       ' row counter

    With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

        'To find out how many rows in D, counting from the last cell (Not blank)
        Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

        ' work on column D
        For R = 1 To Rl  ' start the loop in row 1
            Tmp = .Cells(R, "D").Value
            If Len(Tmp) Then
                Cells(R, "D").Select
                Call Macro1
            End If
            Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
        Next R
    End With
End Sub
```

Macro1:

```
    Dim str As String
    Dim ArrStr() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim y As Long
    Dim RowsAdded As Boolean

    RowsAdded = False
    'Fill variables: str is the value of the active cell, ArrStr splits this value at the comma
    str = ActiveCell.Value
    ArrStr = Split(str, ", ")

    'Loop through each ArrStr to populate each cell below the activecell

    For i = 0 To UBound(ArrStr)
        ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Value = ArrStr(i)
        If RowsAdded = False Then
            For y = 1 To UBound(ArrStr)
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert xlDown
            Next y
            RowsAdded = True
        End If
    Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: It is never a good idea to change the values controlling a for statement in the body of the for loop. e.g. the "Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row" just before the Next R.  If you use F8 to step through your macro you should be able to check by eye that the value you get in R corresponds to the last non empty value in the column.

Comment: Oh.. I placed another "Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row" just before the Next R because I wanted an update onto RI, rather than it being stagnant. Do you have another workaround over it?

Comment: @freeflow Just to add on, the purpose of me putting "Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row", is that since the macro will create a new row for each iteration, I want the RI to update and refresh, so that it could successfully run through every cell in Column D.

Comment: Its not at all clear in your code that you are adding rows.  If this is something that macro1 does you should show the code for macro 1.  Using a for loop on an expanding range is not sensible.  Restructure your code to use a do  loop

Comment: Hi @freeflow, i've already added the set of codes for Macro1. What it does is to actually split a cell up by each ",". And for every splitted string in a cell, it'll create new rows to put it in. What I need the first set of code is to loop through all **cells not empty/blank in column D** and perform macro1... Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code.  You had most of it in your original post above but I think were a bit fixated on the for loop and the number of cells in column D whilst missing that you already had set the exit criteria..

```
Sub testing()

    Dim myRow As Long: myRow = 1
    With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

        'Exit when first non empty cell is encountered
        Do While Len(.Cells(myRow, "D").Value)
            Cells(myRow, "D").Select
            Call macro
            myRow = myRow + 1
        Loop

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: With your set of codes, I seem to be still encountering the same issue as mine before... It seems that when the loop its an empty cell. It will break the loop over at `Do While Len(.Cells(myRow, "D").Value and skip straight to `End With`

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

Just putting out there in case anybody like to see how I did it. But its built upon @freeflow's answer:

```
Sub testing()

    Dim myRow As Long: myRow = 1
    With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

        'Exit when first non empty cell is encountered
        Do While Len(.Cells(myRow, "D").Value) Or Len(.Cells(myRow, "D").Value) = 0
            lastRow = Range("D65000").End(xlUp).Row

            Cells(myRow, "D").Select
            Call Macro1
            myRow = myRow + 1

            If myRow = finalRow Then
                Cells(finalRow, "D").Select
                Call Macro1
                Exit Do
            End If

        Loop

    End With
End Sub
```